# Tareas (task) Dbeaver Comunity Sql script exportar

Tags: db2, dbeaver

Utilizo Dbeaver comunity para todo en el trabajo. Tengo varias maquinas a las que me conecto y me gustaria lanzar una sql con una tarea a todas las maquinas y que me devolviera el resultado de la select. Solo consigo un log diciéndome correcto, pero los datos nada.

No entiendo si que no existe esa opción en la versión gratuita o es algo que no tengo bien configurado. Por favor, si sabéis si se hace os lo agradecería que me lo dijerais. Ya no se que mas mirar.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

No se puede. Al final me he hecho un programa en PYTHON y solucionado el problema